# how can I create correct deployment via Azure pipeline?

Tags: c#, azure, docker, azure-aks

It is a really important question for me because I am creating artifacts after building.
My question: Why does deployment taking long time and returnig this result ?
You can see that my Dockerfile. Why it is taking long time?

There is one repository but 3 projects.XXXX.Web depends on XXXX.HttpApi.Host and XXXX.IdentityServer.I am trying to build and deploy multible Docker image in a same time .I want to share Identityserver log in azure pipeline:

Dockerfile.XXXX.IdentityServer:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5001

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/XXXX.IdentityServer/XXXX.IdentityServer.csproj", "src/XXXX.IdentityServer/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/XXXX.IdentityServer/XXXX.IdentityServer.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/XXXX.IdentityServer"
RUN dotnet build "XXXX.IdentityServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "XXXX.IdentityServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "XXXX.IdentityServer.dll"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error that you are providing, we cannot assume that it stems from your scripts, although that is possible.

> 0/1 nodes are available 1 insufficient cpu

That means, that the kubernetes node, you are trying to deploy to is not available, because it does not have enough cpu resources available.

I would suggest, you try to start troubleshooting there first

```
kubectl get nodes
kubectl describe node [name]
```

And then check, if one of your nodes, or your single node has that error message. From experience: reboot first.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated my question to keep my question more clear. Can you look at my question again? I added some screenshots below.

Comment: How much resources does your cluster have? If that is a development machine and your 1 identity-server pod already consumes 2 cores, chances are theres not much left for the other pods

Comment: I updated my question "kubectl get all -n default" to show all situations maybe it gives you inspiration.